# Como crear un rectangulo usando asteriscos en C# (ciclo for)

Tags: c#, bucle-for

(For) Crear un programa que pida al usuario el ancho (por ejemplo, 5) y el alto (por ejemplo, 4) y escriba un rectángulo formado por esa cantidad de asteriscos, Ej.:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento tengo esto:

```
Console.WriteLine("introduce el tamañno de cuadrado");
int tam = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= tam; i++) // 15 lineas 
{
    for (j = 1; j <= tam; j++) // números a cada línea 
        Console.Write("*", j);
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Pero no se como hacer que utilice tambien el valor de el ancho, agradeceria mucho si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Te faltaria pedir otro valor no? uno es el alto, y otro el ancho.. y vos estas pidiendo uno solo...

Comment: Mi estimado @gbianchi es un cuadrado, con un solo valor es mas que suficiente para crear el cuadrado.

Comment: "escriba un rectángulo".. un rectangulo no es un cuadrado ;)

Comment: @NeryOrtez Me piden un rectangulo, es por eso que no se como utilizar 2 valores que le pediria al usuario.
En lo que llevo de codigo solamente le pido uno, pero lo he dejado asi porque queria ver si eso funcionaba. Pero como es un rectangulo, tengo que pedirle otro valor y utilizarlo para definir alto y ancho.

Comment: @RicardoPortillo, tenés que ser consistente en tu pregunta y codigo... Mira como nos hemos revuelto por eso xD

Comment: @gbianchi Si, tengo que pedirle otro valor. De momento lo habia dejado asi solamente para probrar.

Comment: ok. entonces el problema es que no sabes como pedir otro valor? porque el ejercicio esta casi terminado.. solo pides otro valor y lo usas en el otro for y listo...

Comment: Por favor, lee los enlaces que te pase para que tu pregunta sea consistente.. y luego de ello, explica bien cual es el problema que tenes con el ejercicio.

Comment: @RicardoPortillo Nos gustaría que formaras parte activa de la comunidad de esSO. Por eso te invitamos a leer los enlaces que gbianchi te indicó al principio. Allí aprenderás a hacer preguntas que llamen la atención, como ganar medallas y reputación y más. Esperamos que sigas participando en la comunidad y no te nos vayas después de esta pregunta ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta algo como esto:
En donde v es el número de líneas y h es el número de caracteres por línea.

```
            int i, j;
            for (i = 1; i <= v; i++) // numero de lineas lineas 
            {
                var line = "";
                for (j = 1; j <= h; j++)// números a cada línea 
                {
                    line = line + "*";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final lo pude completar de la manera que me dijiste.

Comment: @RicardoPortillo si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada y/o vota positivo. De ese modo la publicación quedará completa.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Gracias por la sugerencia, ya la habia marcado pero como soy nuevo decia que mi opinion si se tomaba en cuenta pero no apareceria en los votos.
De igual forma ya esta hecho.

Answer (score 5):

Tenés que pedir (asi como lo estas haciendo con el alto) el largo y guardarlo en una variable acorde.

Luego usas cada variable en el for indicado

```
Console.WriteLine("introduce el alto del rectangulo");
int alto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("introduce el ancho del rectangulo");
int ancho = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= alto; i++) // For para el alto 
{
    for (j = 1; j <= ancho; j++) // For para el ancho
        Console.Write("*", j);
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yo me lo encontré divertido, así que he puesto esta forma, con solo un ciclo:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
  int Ancho, Alto; string Asteriscos = null;

  Console.Write("Escriba el ancho: "); // Pedimos la anchura.
  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Ancho))
    return;
  Console.Write("Escriba el alto: "); // Pedimos altura
  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Alto))
    return;

  Asteriscos = new string('*', Ancho); // Creamos los asteriscos bonitos.
  for (int i = 0; i < Alto; i++) 
  {
    // Imprimimos asteriscos como sea necesario.
    if (i == 0 || i == (Alto - 1))
      Console.WriteLine(Asteriscos);
    else
      Console.WriteLine("*{0," + (Ancho - 2) + "}*", ' ');
  }
}
```

Lo único que esto hace es escribir un valor u otro dependiendo del valor de la variable del ciclo (`i`), si se encuentra en la primera o la última posición, escribe un montón de asteriscos, de lo contrario, solo escribe 2 asteriscos y aplica formato a la salida para hacer la forma.

Nótese la forma de conseguir los valores de entrada, estos no controlan la entrada de un valor negativo o si el valor de la anchura o la altura el válida para realizar la figura.

Algunos resultados:

```
Escriba el ancho:  5    Escriba el ancho:  10
Escriba el alto:  5     Escriba el alto:  6
*****                   **********
*   *                   *        *
*   *                   *        *
*   *                   *        *
*****                   *        *
                        **********
```

Aquí te dejo un [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ImpassionedSpanishSpheres)

Saludos :)

Answer (score 3):

Sé que el ejercicio es sobre el bucle `for` y que ya tienes bastantes respuestas, pero te voy a poner una pequeña alternativa que es algo más eficiente.

Hasta el momento casi todas las respuestas son como esto (en pesudo-código):

```
para i de 0 a alto 
  para j de 0 a ancho
    escribe "*"
  escribe salto de línea
```

Esto va a generar el cuadrado que quieres, pero no es realmente eficiente porque estás realizando la misma operación muchas veces y siempre con el mismo resultado. De hecho, el orden de complejidad algorítmica es O(n<sup>2</sup>), lo cual está lejos de ser ideal.

La cosa es que las líneas son siempre las mismas, por lo que no necesitas generar una nueva cada vez, te basta con generarla una vez con un `for` (guardándolo en una cadena), y luego con otro bucle `for` lo escribes tantas veces como necesites. De ese modo el orden de complejidad algorítmica se reducirá a O(n).

```
Console.Write("Introduce el ancho del cuadrado: ");
int ancho = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Introduce el alto del cuadrado: ");
int alto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

string linea = "";

// aquí generas la cadena a escribir por pantalla
for (int i = 1; i <= ancho; i++)
  linea += "* ";

// aquí muestras la cadena tantas veces como el alto
for (int j = 1; j <= alto; j++) 
  Console.WriteLine(linea);
```

Lo puedes ver [funcionando en este repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/QuizzicalHoarseArchitecture).

Comment: Espero haber hecho bien las cuentas de la complejidad algorítmica, llevo algún tiempo sin practicar eso :-/

Answer (score 2):

Con esto deberia de quedar mi estimado.

```
Console.WriteLine("introduce el ancho del rectangulo");
int ancho = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("introduce el largo del rectangulo");
int largo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= ancho; i++)  
{
for (j = 1; j <= largo; j++) 
    Console.Write("* ", j);
Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Console.Write("Dime el alto: ");
            int h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // se pide el alto
            Console.Write("Dime el ancho: ");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // se pide el ancho

            for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++) // se representa el alto
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                for (int j = 1; j <= a; j++) Console.Write("*", j); // se representa el ancho
            }
```